# Ubuntu 14.04.2 i386 boot hangs after installation but is fixed by using live USB's initrd.lz

Tags: boot, kernel, amd-graphics

I recently put Ubuntu 14.04.2 (i386) on a AMD Kabini AM1 5350 CPU + Gigabyte AM1M-S2H mobo using live USB. The installation went smoothly but the system does not get into GDM and hangs after I select the entry in GRUB. The symptom is very similar to this thread "[Black screen while installing 14.04 on AMD Kabini](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223773)".

After hours of poking around and following this thread "[Graphics Resolution- Upgrade /Blank Screen after reboot](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1743535)", I still could not get the system to boot. I have tried numerous kernel options by pressing "e" in the grub screen, and editing the kernel line, e.g. adding "text" to force not to use text mode, using different GFXMODE options reported by the "vbeinfo" from GRUB, and etc.

Since the live USB works and this seems like a early kernel booting problem, on a hunch I copied the kernel image + initrd.img from the live USB to `/boot` and rebooted the machine to GRUB:

- with both "vmlinuz" + "initrd.lz" replaced, I can boot to the system (as expected)
- with only "vmlinuz" replaced, I still see the same problem
- with only "initrd.lz" replaced, the system finishes boot without issues.

So something is different between the initrd.lz shipped with the live USB image, and the one that gets installed on my system

After figuring out this might be due to an issue with the driver of the AMD APU, I tried to install the fglrx driver following the guide, but the installation failed due to "unmet dependencies"

```
$ sudo apt-get install fglrx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Apparently there are other ATI users complaining about similar driver installation failures on 14.04.2, and seems to be a bug (launchpad #1424491, fix in progress).

I guess I'll have to wait a bit for the solution and keep using the live USB image for now.

Comment: So with a bit more digging, I managed to get the two initrd files decompressed and make a comparison. And the initrd shipped with the live USB image appears to come with a folder with AMD radeon FW, but this is not found with the installed initrd...

`lib/firmware/radeon/KABINI_ce.bin` ... 

So I guess I'll need to find a way to install or update my initrd image. 

For anyone interested, I found this [link] (https://www.linux.com/learn/linux-training/92607-the-kernel-newbie-corner-qinitrdq-and-qinitramfsq-whats-up-with-that) very useful for understanding initrd & initramfs.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here...

I am now able to boot into the system after including the `radeon` and `radeonfb` modules into the initramfs.

I followed [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1412132), basically

1. find out the dependencies of `radeon` and `radeonfb` from
   `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep`
2. create files named `radeon` under
   `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/modules.d/`, and add `radeon` and the
   dependent modules name as content. Do the same for `radeonfb`.
3. run `update-initramfs -u -k all` to update all existing initramfs/initrd on the system
4. make sure that the updated `/boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r)` has the
   module by running `zcat /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) | cpio -it |
   grep -i radeon`

Reboot

Now that I am able to boot, posting the `lspci -v` output of the APU video just for completeness sake

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
        Memory at feb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Expansion ROM at feb40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
```